# Installing from Nuget adds reference to bin directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, package

I'm installing the `AvsAn` (2.1.0) package using the Nuget Package manager. I am expecting the reference path to be to the packages directory, something like:

> C:\app\packages\AvsAn.dll

But a reference to the bin directory is added:

> C:\app\NameSpace\bin\AvsAn.dll

Confusingly this is happening for some packages but not for others (i.e the reference path is to the packages folder, as expected)

## What I've tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the package
- Googling for something similar (I've been unable to find anything)

Comment: I am seeing it for all packages in a project, while those same packages in other projects (all within same solution) are using the "correct" packages path.

Comment: Not sure if it is an answer.  I got ours fixed editing the csproj files.  We had some versions that were mixed up.  Different projects using different versions from one another.  The referenced version different than the version listed in the path, etc.  So I just opened all and cleaned them to be the same.

Comment: @DavidMartin that worked! I commented out the all of the Content Include & Reference Include references in the .csproj file & next time I added the package it added the correct path. Care to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8):

We found that different projects within the same solution were using different versions from one another.  Additionally, a single project might have a version listed in the `<Reference>` element from the version listed in the `HintPath`.

We simply went through each .csproj file and manually edited them to get everything in sync.

- Find the line that begins with `<Reference` that includes the information for the dll in question.
- This line should indicate a version.  For example: `<Reference Include="SomeAssembly, Version=4.0.54">`.  *There may be some additional text after this such as `Culture` and/or `PublicKey`, etc.  We're just interested in the Version attribute.*
- Make a note of this Version.
- Now check the `<HintPath>`element within `<Reference`, it will contain the path to that dll that VS will expect (where VS will look first).
- This path will also contain a version `..\packages\SomePackage.4.0.56\lib\net45\SomeAssembly.dll` (for example - in our case it was Service Stack packages).  While this isn't technically a version (it's just a path to a file on your system), it will typically correspond to the version of the dll.
- You need to make sure that these two things are in sync - **that the path listed actually exists and that it leads to the expected dll.**

In our case we were moving from ServiceStack 4.0.54 to 4.0.56.  Some of the `Include` references were to 4.0.56 while the path still pointed to the 4.0.54 version. Because the hint path did not point to the expected dll VS looked elsewhere and it found what it believed to be an acceptable match in the project's `\bin\debug` directory.  This was not the correct version.

It will be up to your specific situation as to which to change and to what.

This was most likely caused by poor merges.

---

Additionally we cleared out the `\bin` and `\packages` directories underneath the project folder.  Reloaded solution and let Nuget restore. This is just to clear things out so that Nuget can pull down just the packages, and their versions, that it needs.  And it prevents VS from using wrong versions that may be located in the project's `\bin` directory.  Both are safe to delete.  The `\packages` folder will be recreated and populated via Nuget restor, and the `\bin` directory will be recreated and populated upon the next build of the solution.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more - should I remove all of the bin references that look like this: `<Content Include="bin\AvsAn.dll" />`. Also, should I be leaving the `Reference Include` such as: `<HintPath>..\packages\AvsAn.2.1.0.0\lib\net20\AvsAn.dll</HintPath>`

I'm unsure what you mean you manually edited them to get everything in sync - could you explain in more detail please?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain what you meant. I have one question - the solution I am working on has `Content Include`s to the bin dir for packages that have `Reference Include`s - should I just remove them? (I don't fully understand the implications of doing this)

Comment: I did not have any inccorrect references so I did not have to edit the .csproj file , however clearing the bin and packages folders and rebuilding did the trick